# Render menu after child component change in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, frontend

I'm trying to implement simple page using React - now I've got main component called Layout:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import { NavMenu } from './NavMenu';
import SummaryBanner from './SummaryBanner';

export class Layout extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div className='container-fluid'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-sm-3'>
                    <NavMenu />
                    <SummaryBanner />
                </div>
                <div className='col-sm-9'>
                    { this.props.children }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

In children defined in this.props.children I've got component representing simple wizard - form with few steps - each part is submitted separately. 
Component **SummaryBanner** contains steps of wizard already submitted /all data are received by calling API using fetch method/.
The only problem is, component **SummaryBanner** is not re-rendered on submit.

How it's possible to do this - force to re-render child from another child component?

Many thanks for any advice.

EDIT: Here is a code of **SummaryBanner** component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ApplicationState } from '../store';
import * as GlobalStore from '../store/GlobalVariables';

interface FetchDataExampleState {
    collections: CollectionOfQuestions[];
}

type SummaryBannerProps =
    GlobalStore.GlobalState;

class SummaryBanner extends React.Component<SummaryBannerProps, FetchDataExampleState> {
    constructor(props: SummaryBannerProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { collections: [] };

        if (this.props.sessionId !== '' && this.props.sessionId !== undefined) {
            fetch(this.props.clientSessionURL + '/' + this.props.sessionId + '/actions/get_main_collections', { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' } })
                .then(response => response.json() as Promise<CollectionOfQuestions[]>)
                .then(data => {
                    this.setState({ collections: data });
                });
        }
    }

    public render() {
        return <ul className="nav metismenu summary-banner" id="side-menu" ref="menu">
            <li className="nav-header">
                <div className="dropdown profile-element"> <span>
                </span>
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" className="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                        <span className="clear"> <span className="block m-t-xs"> <strong className="font-bold summary-banner-header">Summary</strong>
                        </span></span> </a>
                </div>
            </li>

            {(this.state.collections === null || this.state.collections.length === 0) ? (<li>No collection available</li>) :
                (
                    this.state.collections.map((collection, nodeIndex) => {
                        return <li key={collection.id}>  {/* Separate collection */}
                            <NavLink to={'/questions/' + collection.id} activeClassName='fa fa-th-large'>
                                <span className="nav-label summary-banner-label">{collection.name}</span>
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                    }))
            }
        </ul>;
    }
}

interface CollectionOfQuestions {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    type: string;
    id: string;
    orderInSession: number;
    totalNumberOfCollections: number;
    nodes: CollectionOfNodes[];
}

interface CollectionOfNodes {
    code: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    hasAdditionalQuestion: boolean;
    type: string;
    id: string;
    questions: Question[];
}

interface Question {
    name: string;
    text: string;
    description: string;
    productCore: string;
    type: string;
    answers: Answer[];
    possibleAnswers: string[];
    id: string;
}

interface Answer {
    text: string;
}

export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.globalVariables,
    GlobalStore.actionCreators
)(SummaryBanner) as typeof SummaryBanner;
```

Comment: For SummaryBanner re-render there must be some sort of state or props change inside to component. Can you please add codes from SummaryBanner? How do you change the data you show inside the SummaryBanner?

Comment: @bennygenel I've edited my question. Many thanks for response!

Comment: Don't use async operations like fetch in the constructor, by the time the fetch will return the `render` method already invoked. Do this in `componentDidMount` life cycle method

Comment: Not saying this is not a good change but `componentDidMount` is called after the first `render` so it will render anyway before the fetch is completed.

Comment: You can't avoid the first render no matter what. you can conditionally render things. so if you want to show a blank page or a loading indicator you can render it on the first render and after the fetch callback updated your state you can render your content (which the OP is doing anyway).

Comment: I've just tried to implement solution based on second answer, but function and/or property value is not passed into child, even if I used reactClone. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that comes to my mind first:

Keep the `collections` state in `Layout` component and pass it as a prop to `SummaryBanner`. Then use [`React.cloneElement()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) in `Layout` to pass `onSubmit` prop to the wizard, like this:

```
<div className='col-sm-9'>
  {React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(this.props.children), {
    onSubmit: this._onSubmit,
  })}
</div>
```

Call the `_onSubmit` prop from the form and implement `_onSubmit` in `Layout` so that it updates the `collections` state.

Comment: Many thanks for response, I'm trying to implement it this way but property is not passed into child: `<div className='col-sm-9'>
                    {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child => React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(child), {
                        something: this.props.sessionId
                    })))}
                </div>` Property _something_ has value in parent, but in child is empty

Comment: I don't see why it would not work. Did you try to test by changing the `this.props.sessionId` to some static string like `"test"` and see if that works in children? I made small test case with similar setup [in codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/7z667w28jq) and it works, maybe you can use that as a reference and see what you might have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use fetch or any async operations inside the `constructor`, by the time the fetch is returned from the server, the `render` method already invoked.
You can use the life cycle method `componentDidMount` [DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).
Move this code from the constructor:

```
componentDidMount(){
if (this.props.sessionId !== '' && this.props.sessionId !== undefined) {
            fetch(this.props.clientSessionURL + '/' + this.props.sessionId + '/actions/get_main_collections', { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' } })
                .then(response => response.json() as Promise<CollectionOfQuestions[]>)
                .then(data => {
                    this.setState({ collections: data });
                });
        }
}
```